# How can I move my GameObject instantly to part of screen that is touched?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am having trouble. I would like to simply move my game object instantly (no animation) to the part of screen that is touched. I don't want the object to be draggable. I only want the user to be able to move the object by touching the area on the screen, not dragging. In my code it is detecting the touch, but the object disappears as soon as I touch somewhere on the screen (testing on my iOS phone). This is a 2D game. I'm not sure if this might be effecting it, but for my game the camera is always moving downwards.

This is in my Update() function:

```
        if(Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began) 
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
            Vector3 touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(touch.position.x, touch.position.y, 0));                
            transform.position = touchPosition;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the problem is that you are specifying 0 as the depth.

[image]

Let **C** be your Camera. You camera looks into space and renders all the objects it can see, as long as the object is not too far away (**d > far**) and not too close (**d < near**).
When you called

```
Vector3 touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(
                            new Vector3(touch.position.x, touch.position.y, 0));
```

you basically said: I need to find a point that lies on a ray, starting at **C** (`Camera.main`) and travelling towards **M** (`touch.position`). To get a specific point on that ray, you have to specify the distance along that ray: **d**. As you set **d** to 0, what you get is exactly **C**, which is not only too close to the camera, it is actually **on** the camera. **d < near** applies, so any object at that `touchPosition` would not be rendered.

Long story short: make sure **near < d < far**, and you will get a `touchPosition` on which you can place objects and have them rendered.

```
float d = Camera.main.nearClipPlane + 2f; // added some buffer to accommodate for object dimensions
Vector3 touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(
                            new Vector3(touch.position.x, touch.position.y, d));
```